# Is there away to echo another foreach array values in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach

Below I have 2 foreach loops I'll like to display the first foreach loop values in my second foreach loop but whenever i try only the first array value gets displayed. below is my code

```php
<?php
  $order_id = $order->get_id();
                                                 
  $serial_numbers = WC_Serial_Numbers_Query::init()->from( 'serial_numbers' )->where( 'order_id', intval( $order_id ) )->get();
  foreach ($serial_numbers as $serial_number) {
      $decrypted_key = WC_Serial_Numbers_Encryption::maybeDecrypt( $serial_number->serial_key ); 
  }

echo '
  foreach ($order->get_items() as $key => $lineItem) {
      $product_id = $lineItem['product_id'];
      $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
                  <tr>
                  <td>
                  <div>' . $lineItem['name'] . '</div>
                      </td>
                       </tr>
                        <tr>
                         <td>
                         <div>S/N:' . $decrypted_key . '</div>
                         </td>
                         </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>  ';} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display all of the decrypted serial keys for each `WC_Order_Item`. You should place the first foreach loop within the second one.

Comment: That will duplicate the order items eg if we have 3 order items it'll duplicate each item then we'll have 6 instead of 3. if we place the first foreach loop within the second one that's what will happen and we can't add a foreach within an echo. Thank you

Comment: You won't have duplicated order items when you place the first foreach within the second one. You will have duplicated serial keys. Could you perhaps edit your question in a way that you already have the desired HTML written out? So without using PHP. This way the result will be more clear and I could instruct you better on what solution would fit. It's a bit vague now.

Comment: Okay and how do you want to choose what serial key you want to show per Order Item? Since now you're just printing the last time `$decrypted_key` is being set in the foreach loop.

Answer (score -1):

**To display variables values you need to use something called [interpolation](https://riptutorial.com/php/example/22788/string-interpolation).**

to interpolate (insert) a variable and showcase it inside of a string you need to use double-quotes (").

For example:

```
$a = "Hello world";
echo '$a!';
```

will echo '$a!' literally, opposite to:

```
$a = "Hello world";
echo "$a!"
```

will echo "Hello world!"

So give it a shot with double quotes instead of single-quotes.